# JUnit Test both passes and fails - conflict using both ExpectedException and TestWatcher @Rule's

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I figured this out during making this question, but figured it would be a good resource for future people running into the same weird quirk. Treat it as a challenge to your debugging skills.

Using the latest JUnit at the moment, 4.12, this peculiar test both passes and fails - depending how you look at it. Running it will print out the error message - but despite `failed()` being called, it will still not quite count as failed.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.ExpectedException;
import org.junit.rules.TestWatcher;
import org.junit.runner.Description;

public class TestWatcherExpectedExceptionTest {
    @Rule
    public TestWatcher logger = new TestWatcher() {
        @Override
        protected void failed(Throwable e, Description d) {
            System.out.println(d + " FAILED! - are you kidding me ?");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        protected void succeeded(Description d) {
            System.out.println(d + " succeeded!");
        }
    };

    @Rule
    public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

    /**
     * This test both passes and fails, depending how you look at it.
     */
    @Test
    public void photon() throws IOException {
        thrown.expect(IOException.class);
        throw new IOException("Hi");
    }
}
```

As an additional bonus question, during debugging this issue, the test suddenly started to succeed, and call the `succeeded()` method, and I could not, for the life of me, figure out why. As far as I could tell, there were no changes to the code that should have possibly had any impact:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.ExpectedException;
import org.junit.rules.TestWatcher;
import org.junit.runner.Description;

public class TestWatcherExpectedExceptionTest {
    private final class TestLogger extends TestWatcher {
        @Override
        protected void failed(Throwable e, Description d) {
            System.out.println(d + " FAILED! - are you kidding me ?");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        protected void succeeded(Description d) {
            System.out.println(d + " succeeded!");
        }
    }

    @Rule
    public TestWatcher watcher = new TestLogger();

    @Rule
    public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

    /**
     * This test both passes and fails, depending how you look at it.
     */
    @Test
    public void photon() throws IOException {
        thrown.expect(IOException.class);
        throw new IOException("Hi");
    }
}
```

Comment: The "standard" approach for these kinds of questions is to post your own answer to it and mark that as correct, not leave it hanging as a "challenge to debugging skills".

Comment: I wanted to give people a little bit of time to look at it before posting the answer

Comment: There are other sites for such kind of entertainment.

Answer (score 3):

The peculiar answer to why the second test works, and why the first test fails at all is in the way JUnit handles rules - apparently, rules are handled in alphabetical order, based on the field name, and the `TestWatcher` rule is not quite compatible with the `ExpectedException` rule, in that it disregards the exception being expected if the rule is 'interpreted' by JUnit too soon.

So the reason the second test doesn't fail lies in the field names - `watcher` comes alphabetically after `thrown`, but the first test's field name, `logger`, comes before `thrown`. That one was not fun to debug.

Comment: Lets reward you for your efforts. Beyond that: the really reasonable thing would be to write up an entry in the JUnit bug tracker --- if their internal implementation becomes "visible" like this; then they should at least improve their documentation. You see, it might be pretty hard for other people running into this problem finding this question/answer here --- or do you think that the title really points in that direction? (probably you want to add that rule/exception thing somehow in the title)

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, will do both

Comment: Regarding the order of @Rules, look at [RuleChain](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/RuleChain.html) to avoid surprises.

Comment: For completeness, link to junit issue tracker: https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/issues/1436